# Animating scroll to #hash with elements hidden on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem. I have javascript function which scroll to selected element with scroll aniamtion. 
And this works well, but the problem is when i slide up / slide down (show  hide) some element.

if clicked link has class `.show` i show about section. And if link don't have this class i use `.slideUp` function to hide this element. And this creates bug, beacuse now lining is not precise (it aniamtes to wrong places). It looks like javascript takes into account height of hidden element and calculate all wrong. I don't have idea how fix this.
Thanks for help.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
        $(document).on('click','.scroll-ani', function(event){
            if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
                if ($('#about').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#about').slideDown();
                }
            } else {
                // if i replace slideUp with .hide() it will work well, but will not animate this slideUp effect.
                $('#about').slideUp();
            }
            var hash = this.hash;
            if (hash && this.href.slice(0, -hash.length-1) == location.href.slice(0, -location.hash.length-1)) {
                $root.animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 'normal', function() {
                    location.hash = hash;
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things. Instead of using slideDown/Up, change the height with css and give the element a css transition for height. Also maybe use this library for animating scroll: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ .

Maybe the problem is that when you scroll to the element with $root.animate(...) the slideDown animation is not finished and thus the offset().top doesn't get the final correct value. Setting the css height manually and combining with transition should solve the problem (i'm gessing jquery uses traditional js animations and not css transition)